# SMT solves with functions for free varibles

Tags: logic, sat-solvers, smt-solvers

So this sounds like this might lead to an undecidable theory but I thought I would give it a try and ask about it after I found nothing on the subject. I am somewhat interested in finding functions which are counter examples to predicates (or solutions to the inverse rather). I would like to restrict the functions to some small class however (possibly even smaller than primitive recursive) so I think there is hope of this working if I restrict them enough.

Has any work been done in this area? Have any tools been written for such things?

Comment: What kind of predicates? For some kinds what you propose is trivial, for many others it's undecidable.

Comment: The Keyword you are looking for is [Higher-Order Unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29#Higher-order_unification). See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936432/higher-order-unification).

Comment: Perhaps I just don't see the trivial way to use Higher-Order Unification as a means to find solutions to this. For instance $len (xs ++ ys) = (len xs) + (len ys)$. This is clearly easy to find a counter example to (constant 1 function) but I don't see how higher order unification helps me with that.

Comment: $\newcommand\doubleplus{+\kern-1.3ex+\kern0.8ex}$ looks like the latex came out really bad this looks better: $len(xs \doubleplus ys) = len\,\,xs + len\,\,ys$

Answer (score 1):

SMT solvers do support uninterpreted-functions as part of many logics. If there's a counter-example, then they will also print a "counter-example" function, which will be the predicate you're looking for. If you have a concrete example, we can surely see if one can be coded up using Z3.